# remove labels in flot

Tags: jquery, flot

[image]i have two same graph.i want to remove the label from the second one as it is not required.
below is the code for input:

```
var d =
                 [
                     {
                         "label": "ABSOLUTE RETURN", "data": [[18, 40], [19, 20], [20, 100], [21, 100], [22, 100],
                           [23, 100], [24, 100], [25, 100], [26, 100], [27, 100], [28, 100], [29, 100], [30, 100],
                           [31, 50], [32, 40], [33, 60], [34, 70], [35, 40], [36, 100], [37, 100], [38, 100],
                           [39, 100], [40, 100], [41, 100], [42, 100], [43, 100], [44, 100], [45, 100], [46, 100], [47, 100]], "color": "#395A85"
                     }, {
                         "label": "EMERGING MARKETS EQUITY (MGI)", "data": [[18, 30], [19, 20], [20, 0], [21, 0],
                             [22, 0], [23, 0], [24, 0], [25, 0], [26, 0], [27, 0], [28, 0], [29, 0],
                             [30, 0], [31, 50], [32, 20], [33, 0], [34, 0], [35, 0], [36, 0], [37, 0],
                             [38, 0], [39, 0], [40, 0], [41, 0], [42, 0], [43, 0], [44, 0], [45, 0],
                             [46, 0], [47, 0]], "color": "#6EAA38"
                     }, {
                         "label": "ACTIVE GLOBAL EQUITY (MGI) HEDGED VERSION", "data": [[18, 30], [19, 80], [20, 0], [21, 0], [22, 0],
                             [23, 0], [24, 0], [25, 0], [26, 0], [27, 0], [28, 0], [29, 0], [30, 0], [31, 0], [32, 20], [33, 20], [34, 40],
                             [35, 0], [36, 0], [37, 0], [38, 0], [39, 0], [40, 0], [41, 0], [42, 0], [43, 0], [44, 0], [45, 0], [46, 0], [47, 0]], "color": "#00A8C8"
                     }];
```

in scree shot there are 3 labels. i do not want label in second graph. there is any specific property for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the options for the second chart:

```
    legend: {
        show: false   
    },
```

See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mVHC/240/).

Comment: Thanks:) this was the first approach i tried, don't know why it didn't show me change.now tried again and working :) best wishes

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have the label property when you init the second graph

`$.plot("#graph1", [
            { label: "sin(x)", data: d1 },
            { label: "cos(x)", data: d2 },
            { label: "tan(x)", data: d3 }
        ], {
            series: {
                lines: { show: true },
                points: { show: true }
            }, ...`

`$.plot("#graph2", [
             {
            series: {
                lines: { show: true },
                points: { show: true }
            },...`

Comment: var overview = $.plot("#overview", d, {
                series: {
                    stack: true,
                    lines: { show: true, steps: true, fill: true },

                    bars: { show: false },
                },
                grid: {
                    borderWidth: 0
                },

                selection: {
                    mode: "x"
                }
            ,
                //legend: {
                //    container: $("#chartLegend")
                //}

            });   thank you:this is the code for second graph. i am not using any label property.

Comment: ah. looking at the fiddle now. this is a bit weird. :-)